# ReactDOM.render is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am stuck in this code where everything looks fine but still get the error of ReactDOM.render is not a function

below is the code snippet.

```js
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
    
    import App from './App';
    import {TransactionProvider} from './context/TransactionContext';
    import './index.css';
    
    ReactDOM.render (
      <TransactionProvider>
         <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
      </React.StrictMode>, 
    </TransactionProvider>,
        document.getElementById('root'),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this snippet

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './App';
import { TransactionProvider } from './context/TransactionContext';
import './index.css';

const RootComponent = () => (
    <TransactionProvider>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <App />
        </React.StrictMode>,
    </TransactionProvider>
)

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<RootComponent />);
```

Old ReactDOM.render function is now deprecated. Instead, we need to import ReactDOM from the right place, and then use createRoot instead to create a more permanent root element upon which we call the render() method.