# Blank Screen Coming when Running my React App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

When i am running my React App with - npm start - it is showing black screen to me.

**My index.js file code is -**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./store";


ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**My App.js file code is -**

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Signup from "./components/Signup";
import Welcome from "./components/Welcome";
// import { useEffect } from "react";


function App() {
  
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector(state => state.isLoggedIn);
  console.log(isLoggedIn);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <header>
        <Header />
      </header>
      <main>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
          { isLoggedIn && <Route path="/user" element={<Welcome />} />}
        </Routes>
      </main>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Blank Screen View -**

[image]

**Project Running Successfully view -**
[image]

Your valuable suggestions will very be helpful for me.

Comment: does this help .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73422223/reactdom-render-is-not-a-function ...?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set one of the component to be a default that is whenever the page is loaded it will be loaded as a first page

Comment: i think this is the things that you are saying to set as a default -

in index.js file App is set as a default

<Provider store={store}>
   <App />
</Provider>


Is this that you are saying ??